# Merging two prototype chains

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have an existing prototype chain:

```
{ name: 'layer2' } <- { name: 'layer1' }
```

. I want to be able to 'rebase' this chain on top of a different prototype chain, let's say: `Element.prototype`. Is this possible?

```
var layer1 = { name: 'layer1' };
var proto = Object.create(one);

proto.name = 'layer2';

// prototype chain: layer2 <- layer1 <- Object

var ElementProto = Element.prototype;

// desired prototype chain: layer2 <- layer1 <- ElementProto <- Object
```

**NOTE:** *I don't want to use `__proto__`, and I don't want to mutate either of the two original prototype chains, as they may be used elsewhere.*

Comment: No, you need to duplicate it in the matter you wish.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah ES5 is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NB: I have no complete solution (yet), but in outline I believe you would have to:

Start at the top of your prototype chain and for that "type" use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` to find the properties and for each of those use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`.

Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to get the `__proto__` field to find the next type in the chain.

I think you'll need to do the above bit recursively, until you get to `Object.prototype`.

Then, recursing back up the chain, use `Object.create` to create a new object that shares the same properties as the original prototypes, but which has a different `prototype` object (that being either the one you're trying to insert in the chain or the result of the previous pass).

**EDIT** My attempt is at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/xkX5v.  It uses ES5 methods to safely attempt to ensure that non-enumerable properties remain as such, and that getters and setters work as expected.

There are certain flaws I can see, but haven't tried to resolve, e.g. 1. the newly created type has no constructor 2. there's no way to invoke the constructor of the function that was added to the prototype chain, etc.

Comment: @wilsonpage but note that your own `mixin` function is unsafe because `for ... in` will also include any (enumerable) properties found on the prototype chain.